# PFUser becomeInBackground Not Found

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

On parse's blog, they say you can use:

```
[PFUser becomeInBackground:@"session-token-here"; block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // The token could not be validated.
            } else {
                // The current user is now set to user.
            }
        }];
```

for handling login on a custom basis.  However, I get multiple errors when trying to run this code, basically saying it can't find an instanceMethod for becomeInBackground.  What's going on?

Comment: You have a semi-colon in the middle of the line `here"; block`

Comment: @Wain I remove that and get No known class method for selector "becomeInBackground"

Comment: Update the code and paste the exact error text

Comment: @Wain the exact code is what I had posted without the semicolon in it, and the exact error text is what I have already typed in my comments.

Comment: If you removed the semi-colon then the stated error doesn't make sense though...